# How does tikz graph a parabola when only given two points?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know this is probably a dumb question, but when solving for the coefficients of a parabola given by $y = ax^2 + bx + c$, we have three constants a,b and c that control the shape of it. So that means that if we wanted to solve for these constants, we need a linear system of three equations, like so:

$y_1 = ax_1^2 + bx_1 + c$

$y_2 = ax_2^2 + bx_2 + c$

$y_3 = ax_3^2 + bx_3 + c$

So we need three differnet points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)$ to get a definitive shape for the parabola.

However, the `parabola` command only takes two points. Suppose those two points were fixed. How is tikz always able to generate exactly the same parabola? Additionally, I don't really understand the `bend` command. How does that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `parabola` without any options

In

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (x0, y0) parabola (x1, y1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

a partial parabola with its axis of symmetry at `x = x0` and goes through `(x0, y0)` and `(x1, y1)` is drawn. This gives enough info to get the exact function of that parabola.

- The function of a parabola with its axis of symmetry at `x = x0` and goes through `(x0, y0)` is `y - y0 = a (x - x0)^2`.
- Using condition that this parabola also goes through `(x1, y1)`, `a` is solvable and `a = (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)^2`.

Therefore `\draw (x0, y0) parabola (x1, y1);` draws the image of function

```
y = a(x - x0)^2 + y0, x in [x0, x1],
```

where `a = (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)^2`.

#### `parabolar` with option `bend={<absolute coordinate>}`

```tex
\draw (x0, y0) parabola[bend={(x2, y2)}] (x1, y1);
```

is equivalent to

```tex
\draw (x2, y2) parabola (x0, y0)
      (x2, y2) parabola (x1, y1);
```

Hence two partial parabola is drawn.

#### `parabola` with options `bend={<relative coordinate>}` and `bend pos=<fraction>`

```tex
\draw (x0, y0) parabola[bend={+(dx, dy)}, bend pos=k] (x1, y1);
```

where `(dx, dy)` is a coordinate and `k` is a fraction like `0.5` or `0.0`, is equivalent to

```tex
\draw (x2, y2) parabola (x0, y0)
      (x2, y2) parabola (x1, y1);
```

where `(x2, y2) == ($(x0, y0)!k!(x1, y1) + (dx, dy)$)`, or `x2 = x0 + k * (x1 - x0) + dx` and `y2 = y0 + k * (y1 - y0) + dy`.

#### `parabola` with other options

Other three `parabola` options can all be seen as style options, where

```tex
parabola height=<dimension> == bend pos=0.5, bend={+(0pt, <dimension>)}
bend at start               == bend pos=0.0, bend={+(0, 0)}
bend at end                 == bend pos=1.0, bend={+(0, 0)}
```

This completes the (inductive) explanation of the `parabola` operation and its specific options provided by tikz.

#### An example

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] 
        (0, -4) grid (3, 2);
  % simple parabolae
  \draw (1, -1) parabola (0, 0)  % y = x^2, x in [0, 1]
        (1, -1) parabola (3, 2); % y = 3/2 * (x - 1)^2 - 1, x in [1, 3] 
  % bend={<absolute coordinate>}
  \draw[yshift=-1cm, blue]
        (0, 0) parabola[bend={(1, -1)}] (3, 2);
  % bend={<relative coordinate>}, bend pos=<fraction>
  \draw[yshift=-2cm, red]
        (0, 0) parabola[bend={+(0, -1.666)}, bend pos=0.333] (3, 2) -- cycle;
  % domonstrate
  \draw[yshift=-2cm, red, |<->|]
        (1, 0.666) -- node[above, sloped] {\tiny $1.666$} (1, -1);
  % restore bend={<relative coordinate>} to bend={<absolute coordinate>}
  \draw[yshift=-3cm, orange]
        (0, 0) parabola[bend={($(0, 0)!.333!(3, 2) + (0, -1.666)$)}] (3, 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So basically, `parabola` draws "half" parabolas between points?

Comment: @Kookie By default, yes. With `bend pos=0.5, bend={+(0, 0)}`, the parabola is "complete".